# Is it possible to preview .resx files in Visual Studio for Macbook?

Tags: c#, macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac, resx

I'm creating a project in Visual Studio Mac using resource files with .resx extension. In the version of VS for Windows, when you double-click on the file, a preview of the file opens as shown in the image below.

On the Mac, when doing the same thing, the preview does not open, instead, the source code is opened and I did not find any option to do this.

I was wondering if there is any way to display the preview on Mac. I use a Macbook Air M1.

[image]

Comment: Did you find out something useful?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio for Mac doesn't (yet?) have a visual editor for .resx files. There are however third-party tools for visual editing of .resx files available for macOS.

Comment: can you name these third-party tools you are talking of? And/or recommend one of these.

Comment: A quick google found [RESX Editor](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/resx-editor/id1484612171) and a blog post "[How to edit a .resx file on Mac OS?](https://medium.com/@jdassonval/how-to-edit-a-resx-file-on-mac-os-c4dac927145c)". But I can't make a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is still nothing that can help on mac. There is this thread on the forum: [ResX file editor for VS Mac](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/create-resx-files-editor-like-in-visual-studio-201/376733), requesting some resource for this since 2017 but still no progress.